# Nested HTML Tags in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I had a question, re: creating nested html tags in Rails, since I am just learning rails.

Basically, I am trying to refactor some code that looks like this:

```
<a id="myid" href="/mylink">MainLinkText<span>Subtext</span></a>
```

However, when I use the contact_tag inside a link_to, I can't get it to display the MainLinkText.
My code looks like this:

```
link_to content_tag(:span, "Subtext"), mylink_path, :id => "myid"
```

But I don't know how to get the "MainLinkText" in there. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link_to "MainLinkText #{content_tag(:span, "Subtext")}".html_safe, mylink_path, :id => "myid"
```

Comment: Thanks @odiszapc, that worked like a charm! I had tried the interpolation part before I posted my question, but I wasn't doing it right, since the results I got didn't match what I was hoping for (or what your answer provides).

Comment: Ok, but one more thing - be carefull with .html_safe, it's not good idea to use this method anywhere...